# Super mesh analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, mesh-analysis

[image]Please someone help me to write mesh equation.I don't know whether i should consider both the current sources to write first equation or only the independent current source.A current source is in between two mesh so I applied super mesh analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You need just two equations:

1. KCL at the \$1\Omega/V_x/\:\frac{V_x}{ 9}\$ node
2. the mesh equation for the \$1\Omega/2\Omega/3\Omega\$ mesh.

There are two unknowns, \$V_x\$, and \$I\$, in these two equations, hence solve simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Geez, I cannot say how much I ***hate*** the confusion caused by *super-* approaches. A complication that creates more confusion than it solves.

In your case you have three loops:

[image]

Working each clockwise loop starting with the lower left-hand corner, I find:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{Three equations from each loop:}\\\\
0\:\text{V}+V_{15 A}-1\:\Omega\cdot\left(I_1-I_2\right)-V_{\frac19V_x}-2\Omega\cdot\left(I_1-I_2\right)&= 0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V}-2\:\Omega\cdot\left(I_2-I_1\right)+V_{\frac19V_x}-3\:\Omega\cdot\left(I_2-I_3\right)-1\:\Omega\cdot I_2&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V}-1\:\Omega\cdot\left(I_3-I_1\right)-2\:\Omega\cdot I_3-3\:\Omega\cdot\left(I_3-I_2\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\\text{Two obvious relationships added to the above:}\\\\
I_2-I_1&=\frac19 V_x
\\\\
V_x&=3\:\Omega\cdot\left(I_2-I_3\right)
\\\\\text{And a given:}\\\\
I_1&=15\:\text{A}
\end{align*}$$

Using [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), this solves out as:

```
eq1 = Eq( 0 + v15a - 1*(i1-i2) - v19x - 2*(i1-i2), 0 )
eq2 = Eq( 0 - 2*(i2-i1) + v19x - 3*(i2-i3) - 1*i2, 0 )
eq3 = Eq( 0 - 1*(i3-i1) - 2*i3 - 3*(i3-i2), 0 )
eq4 = Eq( i2 - i1, vx/9 )
eq5 = Eq( vx, 3*(i2-i3) )
ans = solve( [ eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5 ], [ i2, i3, v15a, v19x, vx ] )
for i in ans: i, ans[i].subs( { i1:15 } )
    (i2, 17)
    (i3, 11)
    (v15a, 33)
    (v19x, 39)
    (vx, 18)
```

Seriously, just do NOT worry about *super-* anything. It's a total waste of time and it will just make your life worse rather than better.

Instead, just assign unknown voltage differences across your current sources and add a few known, obvious relationships. The rest just falls out.

The concept(s) adds unnecessary mental encumbrances that in the final analysis serve to complicate more than simplify.

Best wishes,

Comment: The reason students are taught the super methods is that what you think are "obvious relationships" are anything but obvious to beginners. The super methods will always work without relying on experience or intuition, and they yield the minimum number of equations necessary (3 in this case instead of your 5). BTW, I think your first equation has an error in the 1\$\Omega\$ term.